# How to compile Arti on Windows?

Tags: windows

I have attempted to compile Arti (https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/arti) on Windows but I get:

```
note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'sqlite3.lib'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like one can follow: https://github.com/dlang-community/d2sqlite3/issues/49#issuecomment-694725249:

> ```
> 1. Download source from [source](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) (https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
>    For example: [source](https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-amalgamation-3310100.zip) `https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-amalgamation-3310100.zip`
>
> 2. Download binary from [binary](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
>    For example: [binary](https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3310100.zip) `https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3310100.zip`
>
> 3. Extract both archives to the same directory
>
> 4. Open **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017** by typing _Developer Command_ in Windows Search
>
> 5. Go to directory where you've extracted **source code** and **binary** files (via opened cmd)
>
> 6. Run
>    `lib /DEF:sqlite3.def /OUT:sqlite3.lib /MACHINE:x64`
> ```

and just copy `sqlite3.lib` to `arti` folder and then `cargo build`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has already been described in [doc/TROUBLESHOOTING.md](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/arti/-/blob/main/doc/TROUBLESHOOTING.md). Under Windows, it is much more convenient to link sqlite library statically instead of copying manually over:

```
cargo build -p arti --release --features static
```